# UniqueForProp utility for typescript failing

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a utility `UniqueForProp` which intended to take an array of objects and *property* expected in the object and produce a union type of possible values across the array:

```
type Get<T, K> = K extends `${infer FK}.${infer L}`
  ? FK extends keyof T
    ? Get<T[FK], L>
    : never
  : K extends keyof T
  ? T[K]
  : never;

type UniqueForProp<T extends readonly Record<string, any>[], P extends string> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Readonly<Get<T[K], P>>;
}[keyof T];
```

And then with the following test case, the expectation is to get the union type `123 | 456`:

```
const data = [
  { id: 123, color: "blue" },
  { id: 456, color: "red" },
] as const;
type Data = typeof data;
type U = UniqueForProp<Data, "id">;
```

And while `123` and `456` *are* part of the union type returned so is a **lot** of other junk:

[image: full type info]

Can anyone help me to clean this up?

> [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mqvqYW)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `T` extends an array, you should index `T` with just `number` rather than `keyof T` because it will also include methods (`concat`, `map`, etc.)

```
type UniqueForProp<T extends readonly Record<string, any>[], P extends string> = {
  [x: number]: Readonly<Get<T[number], P>>;
}[number];

type U = UniqueForProp<Data, "id">; // type is 123 | 456
```

Comment: No need for the mapped type: `type UniqueForProp<T extends readonly Record<string, any>[], P extends string> = Readonly<Get<T[number], P>>;`

Comment: Ah, yeah, I forgot that. :P